# Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Уплотнительные поверхности при открытом положении шара, из-за наличия «мертвых зон», по
всей площади подвержены воздействию агрессивных сред.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1. Желательно обособить обстоятельство, которому в это случае придается дополнительное поясняющее значение: "Уплотнительные поверхности при открытом положении шара, из-за наличия «мертвых зон», по всей площади подвержены воздействию агрессивных сред". без обособления мы имеем три распространенных обстоятельства подряд, и предложение плохо читается.

Вариант 2. "Из-за наличия «мертвых зон» уплотнительные поверхности при открытом положении шара по всей площади подвержены воздействию агрессивных сред". В этом случае нет стечения трех обстоятельств, причинный оборот представлен в основном сообщении.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Вообще говоря, если у автора (с точки зрения технических особенностей) нет желания относить оборот на второй план, то он строит структуру предложения таким образом, чтобы  обособления не требовалось, то есть избегает стечения обстоятельств, затрудняющего чтение и понимание предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, по правилам, здесь запятые не нужны, так как все слова являются разными членами предложения, отвечают на разные вопросы. С большой натяжкой можно допустить авторские запятые там, где они у Вас поставлены, чтобы обособить слова "из-за наличия "мертвых зон", особо подчеркивая, что поверхности подвержены воздействию анресивыных сред именно по причине наличия "мертвых зон"

Answer (score 0):

Лучше, по-моему, оборот "из-за наличия «мертвых зон»" переставить в начало предложения:

*Из-за наличия «мертвых зон» уплотнительные поверхности…*

Comment: Если мёртвые зоны возникают именно при открытом положении шара, то лучше не отделять "зоны" от "положения". Поверхности можно приблизить к глаголу.

При открытом положении шара, из-за наличия «мертвых зон», 
уплотнительные поверхности по всей площади подвержены воздействию агрессивных сред. 

(запятые исключают "открытое положение из-за мёртвых зон")

Comment: Ой, не знаю! Мне в исходном предложении много чего не нравится. Не нравится "по всей площади" (я бы этот оборот вообще выкинул). Не нравится "при открытом положении шара"…

Но не видя перед собой описываемой конструкции, воздержусь-таки от дальнейшего  обсуждения этого предложения.

Comment: Площадь поверхности - измеряемая величина, и в технических текстах естественно ссылаться на часть поверхности через относительную меру площади (например, поверхность на 30 процентов своей площади может обгореть и т.п.) или говорить обо "всей площади" поверхности.

Comment: Alex_ander, я оборот "по всей площади" подвергал сомнению не с позиций его грамматической верности/неверности.
Во-первых. Если речь идёт о поверхности шара в шаровом кране, то некорректно говорить о "уплотнительных поверхностях": у шара только ОДНА поверхность.
Во-вторых. Даже при полностью открытом кране какая-то часть поверхности шара находится вне «мертвых зон» -- а именно та, которая в этом положении шара находится под уплотнением. И потому утверждение "по ВСЕЙ площади" я бы выкинул. Ну или как-то переработал.
В-третьих…

===

Comment: Но это всё уже сверх вопроса о запятых, на который я пытался ответить. Запятые, если оборот "из-за наличия «мертвых зон»" переставить в начало предложения, НЕ НУЖНЫ.

Comment: А я себе представлял раскрывающийся шар с кольцевым уплотнением в месте раскрыва.

Comment: М-да... Улыбнули!